# Javascript dictionary of dictionaries to dictionary based of 2nd tier key

Tags: javascript, object

I have a dictionary of dictionaires:

```
var dic1 = {
  a : {
    x : "ax",
    y : "ay"
  },
  b : {
    x : "bx",
    y : "by"
  }
}
```

And I need to reduce it to a dictionary like this:

```
var dicX = {
  a : "ax"
  b : "bx"
}
```

for the x's, or the following for the y's.

```
var dicY = {
  a : "ay"
  b : "by"
}
```

Now I know that it can be done with a map and reduce operations:

```
let mapped  = Object.keys(dic1).map((k)=>{return {key:k,x:dic1[k].x,y:dic1[k].y}})

let dicX_2 = mapped.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator[current.key] = current.x;
  return accumulator;
},{});

let dicY_2 = mapped.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator[current.key] = current.y;
  return accumulator;
},{});
```

But this above approach seems rather convoluted, and, I was wondering if there is an easier way to reduce the above dimensionality using a one-liner or similar.

Comment: Nice food for the brain!

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no one-liner to do this, although the `map` in your code looks pretty unnecessary. You could just do that in the `reduce` callback itself.

I would however recommend to not use `reduce` at all, and to avoid duplicate code make a simple helper function:

```
function mapObject(o, f) {
    const r = {};
    for (const p in o) // you could use `reduce` here as well, but it doesn't become simpler
        r[p] = f(o[p], p);
    return r;
}
```

Then use it as

```
const dicX = mapObject(dic1, inner => inner.x);
const dicY = mapObject(dic1, inner => inner.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner in plain JavaScript:

```js
const dic1 = {
  a : { x : "ax", y : "ay" },
  b : { x : "bx", y : "by" }
};

const dicX = Object.entries(dic1).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v.x }), {});
const dicY = Object.entries(dic1).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v.y }), {});

console.log(dicX);
console.log(dicY);
```

If you make it into a function, it will be 1.25 lines long though:

```js
const dic1 = {
  a : { x : "ax", y : "ay" },
  b : { x : "bx", y : "by" }
};

const dic = (d, p) =>
  Object.entries(d).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v[p] }), {});

console.log(dic(dic1, 'x'));
console.log(dic(dic1, 'y'));
```

Here is another way without `reduce` and using `Object.assign` to combine the properties from each inner dictionary, but this solution is slightly longer:

```
const dic = (d, p) =>
      Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(d).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v[p] })));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/), your one-liner would look like this:

```js
const {map, prop} = R;

var dic1 = {
  a : {
    x : "ax",
    y : "ay"
  },
  b : {
    x : "bx",
    y : "by"
  }
}

console.log(map(prop('x'), dic1));
console.log(map(prop('y'), dic1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to get the same output. One could be the following one:

```js
var dic1 = {
  a : {
    x : "ax",
    y : "ay"
  },
  b : {
    x : "bx",
    y : "by"
  }
}

const all = Object.values (dic1).flatMap (Object.entries)

const xs = Object.fromEntries (all.filter (([a]) => a == 'x').map (([a, b]) => [b[0], b]))
const ys = Object.fromEntries (all.filter (([a]) => a == 'y').map (([a, b]) => [b[0], b]))

console.log (xs)
console.log (ys)
```

Here's even a nicer one:

```js
var dic1 = {
  a : {
    x : "ax",
    y : "ay"
  },
  b : {
    x : "bx",
    y : "by"
  }
}

const flatten = (by, dict) => 
    Object.fromEntries (
        Object.entries (dict)
              .map (([x, y]) => [x, y[by]])
    )
    
const xs = flatten ('x', dic1)
const ys = flatten ('y', dic1)

console.log ('xs', xs)
console.log ('ys', ys)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```js
let dic1 = {
  a : {
    x : "ax",
    y : "ay"
  },
  b : {
    x : "bx",
    y : "by"
  }
}

let {a: dicX} = {a: { a: dic1.a.x, b: dic1.b.x }}, {a: dicY} = {a: { a: dic1.a.y, b: dic1.b.y }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one generic solution. You create a method that receives the dictionary and the second-level `key` and returns the expected object.

```js
var dic1 = {
  a : {
    x : "ax",
    y : "ay"
  },
  b : {
    x : "bx",
    y : "by"
  }
}

const mapDictionary = (dic, innerProp) =>
{
    return Object.entries(dic).reduce(
        (acc, [key, obj]) => (acc[key] = obj[innerProp], acc),
        {}
    );
}

console.log(mapDictionary(dic1, "x"));
console.log(mapDictionary(dic1, "y"));
```